# Python columns match CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to read in a csv file: `base_list.csv` - CSV file with two columns

Then read in `file_1.csv` and remove and matching values from the `base_list.csv` file, and
write those out to a new csv file called `Dups.csv`

When I run this I am getting the following error:

> emails = set(emails) #"set" removes duplicates in a list TypeError:
>   unhashable type: 'list'

Sample code below:

```
import csv
#gather emails from base_list:
with open("H:\\Python Backups\\DeDup\\ByCSV\\base_list.csv", "rU") as base_file:
    read_base_file = csv.reader(base_file, delimiter=",")
    duplicates_list = []
    rows = [row for row in read_base_file]
    for row in rows:
        duplicates_list.extend(row)
    #extract emails from other csv files (csv_files) from multiple
    #columns in those csv files (email_columns):
    emails = []
    with open("H:\\Python Backups\\DeDup\\ByCSV\\file_1.csv", "rU") as csvfile:
        read_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")     
        email_rows = [r for r in read_csv]
        emails.extend(email_rows)
    #find duplicates from base_list and remove them:
    duplicates = [e for e in emails if e in duplicates_list]
    for dupe in duplicates:
        emails.remove(dupe)
    emails = set(emails) #"set" removes duplicates in a list
    #write the emails to a csv:
    writer = csv.writer(open("H:\\Python Backups\\DeDup\\ByCSV\\Dups.csv", "ab"))
    for email in zip(emails):
        writer.writerow(email)
```

Comment: your question is about removing duplicate lists. This can be achieved by converting them to tuples, using a set and convert to list again. It's a dupe

Comment: actually i think his real problem is that he's trying to add a list to a set, and he's wondering why he's getting the "unhashable" TypeError.  key words: i think

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to store a list in a set.  This isn't possible, because lists are mutable in python and thus unhashable.

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[1,2,3], ['a','b','c']]
>>> set(list_of_lists)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Change `email_rows` to be

```
email_rows = (tuple(r) for r in read_csv)
```

which will create a list of generators of tuples, which is now hashable.

Comment: changed as suggested above still get the same error unhashable type list  - email_rows = (r for r in read_csv)

Comment: ahh, that's probably because the row itself if a list, change it to `(tuple(r) for r in read_csv`.  I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you that fixed the list/tuple syntax error, now the issue is the logic does not work, getting just results from file_1